# How can i do multiline commenting for my feature steps for Calabash with Ruby

Tags: ruby, comments, cucumber, calabash

I was trying to comment multiple steps for my calabash Feature file (Ruby) using """.I'm using # for commenting single lines for my features but cant able to do for multiple lines. Can you please suggest me any ways to comment multiple lines.I'm using latest version of calabash with Ruby v 2.0

Comment: There are ways to comment multiple-line blocks in Ruby, but rdoc won't catch them when processing the documentation from the source file, so you're better off using `#` to comment them.

Answer (score 9):

There are ways to comment code or delineate docstrings in Gherkin:

1. **Single line -> use # symbol**
2. **Multiple lines -> use """ (i.e. three double-quote marks)**

The inspiration for PyString comes from Python.

Friends, *Don't forget to vote* if resolve your issue.

Answer (score 5):

Commenting multiple line in a cucumber feature file is quite possible and as easy.
Just select all the lines you want to comment out and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. this works well in intellij also.
Note: Same key combination can be used to uncomment- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

There are no multiline comments in Gherkin. Just comment every line.

Answer (score 0):

The method with """ leads to a parsing error in my IDE (intelliJ) when executing my Tests.
expected: #EOF, #TableRow, #TagLine, #ExamplesLine, #ScenariosLine, #ScenarioOutlineLine, #Comment, #Empty, got '"""'

So i guess on execution Cucumber really does not like those """.

I prefer the Ctrl+/ way to comment unused Gherkin-Stuff!